# Getting my load more button to stop multiplying and append to the bottom of my listview

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, dynamically-generated

I'm a newbie with jQuery Mobile and I'm working with a list that is dynamically generated with ajax. Now I had some help to get this to load certain amount of items then with a "Load More" button to populate more items into this list. I have a few issues I can't seem to figure out.

1. I can't get the "Load More" to append to the bottom

2 The "Load More" button appends multiple times in my list when clicked. It keeps the last button clicked in place then adds a new one further down.

Here is my code:

**This is what is generating content on page load**

```
function runBrowse() {

        //Check if all fields have a value
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.com",
            data: {firstName: "", middleName: "", lastName: "", resultSize:10},
            success: browseSuccess,
        });
    }

    function runBrowseContinue(restart) {

        //Check if all fields have a value
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.com",
            data: {restartLine: restart, resultSize:10},
            success: browseSuccess,
        });
    }



    function browseSuccess(browseResults){
        $.mobile.changePage('#results');
        restartLine = browseResults.restartLine;
        jQuery.each(browseResults.people,handlePerson);
    }



    //Usage getMoreData(browseResults.restartLine);
    function getMoreData(restartLine){
        if(restartLine){
            runBrowseContinue(restartLine);
        }
    }

    function handlePerson(index, value) {
        var output = '';

        // Add these returns to listview
        output += '<li>' + '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' + '<p>' + value.height + '</p>' + '<p>' + value.weight + 'lbs.' + '</p>' + '</li>';
        $('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');
    }
```

**This is the Load More code**

```
$loadMore = $('ul').children('.load-more');
    $loadMore.bind('click', function () {
        var out = [];
        out.push(getMoreData(restartLine));
        $('ul').append(out.join('')).append($loadMore).listview('refresh');
    });
```

**This is my HTML**

```
  <ul data-role="listview" class="listContent" id="listview">

    <li class="load-more"><a href="#">Load More</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help :)

**Screen shot of this:**

http://cl.ly/2l0w3I0G0f112f381g1f

http://cl.ly/0N002X2Z45320r2Y1K38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots it appears as though the `handlePerson` function is adding more "people" to the list without moving the "Load More" button to the bottom, which will account for having list-items below the "Load More" button.

```
function handlePerson(index, value) {
    var output = '';

    // Add these returns to listview
    output += '<li>' + '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' + '<p>' + value.height + '</p>' + '<p>' + value.weight + 'lbs.' + '</p>' + '</li>';
    var $loadMore = $('#listview').children('.load-more');
    $('#listview').append(output).append($loadMore).listview('refresh');
}
```

When you append a DOM element that already exists, jQuery will move it to the new location and remove it from the old: http://api.jquery.com/append

I would like to warn against this however. This makes two DOM manipulations for every index ("person"). It would be better to buffer all of the list-item output, and append it at once, which will take a slight re-flow of your code:

```
function browseSuccess(browseResults){
    $.mobile.changePage('#results');
    restartLine = browseResults.restartLine;
    var out = [];
    jQuery.each(browseResults.people,function (i, v) {
        out.push(handlePerson(i, v));
    });
    var $loadMore = $('#listview').children('.load-more');
    $('#listview').append(out.join('')).append($loadMore).listview('refresh');
}

function handlePerson(index, value) {
    return '<li>' + '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' + '<p>' + value.height + '</p>' + '<p>' + value.weight + 'lbs.' + '</p>' + '</li>';
}
```

As you can see it would be easy to just remove the `handlePerson()` function all together and place it's code inside the `$.each()` loop in the `browseSuccess()` function.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper that is the other thing is we are early in development and I know this code can be cleaned up. I was thinking it was the handlePerson that was causing this error, but because I'm new I didn't know the best way to do this. Let me give this a whirl.